# Iterating through my Datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, filter, iteration

I'm trying to do a text filter for my DataGridView.

When the text in my textbox is changing, i'm trying to make all the non matching rows unvisible. But my iterating loop keeps telling me after I changed the text in my textbox "An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication1.exe"

This is my Datagridview Code:

```
    private void Icon_Picker_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    //    string[] first = {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17"};

        int j = 0;
        //image directory
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(imagepath);

        //getting all files from the Directory
        foreach(FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles())
        {

            try
            {
                this.img16x16.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(file.FullName));
                this.img32x32.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(file.FullName));


                while (j < img16x16.Images.Count)
                {
                    var row = new DataGridViewRow();

                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
                    dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[0].Value = file.Name;

                    //Resizing icons to 16x16 icons
                    img16x16.ImageSize = new Size(16, 16);

                    //adding icons to the datagridview
                    dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[1].Value = img16x16.Images[j];

                    //Resizing icons to 32x32 icons
                    img32x32.ImageSize = new Size(32, 32);

                    //adding icons to the datagridview
                    dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[2].Value = img32x32.Images[j];
                    j++;

                }

            }catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This is not an image file");
            }
        }          
    }
```

And this is my code when i'm changing the textbox text

```
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
            if (!row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Contains(txtFilter.Text))
            {
                row.Visible = false;

            }
            else 
            {

                row.Visible = true;
            }
```

Comment: Which exact line is throwing the exception?

Comment: if (!row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Contains(txtFilter.Text)).

Comment: So the cell is empty. Do make sure to check for this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should check for null values in cell,

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
     if(row.Cells[0].Value!=null)
      {
      //code
      }
    }
```

more over you should check for dataGridView1.Rows.Count should not be equal to zero as well.